# Restarting an RKObjectRequestOperation with new authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

Hi guys,

Do you know if you can "restart" an `RKObjectRequestOperation` with a new authentication in `RestKit 0.20.3`?
If the first one fails, I want to change the authentication of the `RKObjectRequestOperation` and start it from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't documented as reusable so even if it did work now you couldn't guarantee that it will continue to work in the future. The request and the response descriptors you use to create the operation are immutable so you can easily extract those to create a new operation instance and set your new auth details.

As an aside, the operation contains a state machine and internally utilises several other asynchronous operations. Don't rely on reusability.

Comment: I'm going to solve this problem in another way then. Thanks for the help!